# Url doesn't change after hitting the "Next" button with selenium/python

Tags: python, selenium

I scrape data from this url then click the `Next` button and wait 10 seconds before using requests and bs4 to scrape the next page but the url doesn't change so I just end up scraping the original page data twice. I've tried `WebDriverWait` until elements on the first page become stale as well as trying to use requests to get the xhr log api call directly (I am not well-versed in ajax however) and can't find a solution. Here is the code as it stands:

```
loop = True
        while loop:
            try:
                current_url = driver.current_url
                next_btn = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Next"]')))
                actions = ActionChains(driver)
                actions.move_to_element(next_btn).perform()
                if next_btn:
                    next_btn.click()
            except Exception as e:
                current_url = driver.current_url
                loop = False
                print(e,f"somewhere in {current_url} while loop")
            else:
                time.sleep(10)
                next_page = driver.current_url
                get_page_content(next_page)
                break
```

Here is the URL of the first page: https://www.hunterdouglas.com/locator/results?address=San%20Ramon&country=US&source=

Any direction would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Seems like you're getting the page source here.  That won't change in the case of a Javascript DOM update.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested I got this to work by just using selenium. Here is the code the argument `data` is just the name of the city I'm submitting to the `master_function(data)`

```
def get_links(page):
    for p in page:
        for l in p.find_elements_by_tag_name("a"):
            link = l.get_attribute('href')
            if link != None:
                link_split = link.split('\n')
                for l in link_split:
                    if "http" in link:
                        test_list.append(link)
                        
def master_function(data):
    for d in data:
        base_url = "https://www.hunterdouglas.com/locator"
        driver.get(base_url)
        url = pop_up_one(driver)
        submit(url,driver,d)
        loop = True
        while loop:
            try:
                current_url = driver.current_url
                next_btn = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Next"]')))
                actions = ActionChains(driver)
                actions.move_to_element(next_btn).perform()
                if next_btn:
                    next_btn.click()
            except Exception as e:
                current_url = driver.current_url
                loop = False
                print(e,f"somewhere in {current_url} while loop")
            else:
                time.sleep(1)
                page = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="loc-results"]')))
                get_links(page)
```